# Unable to get input data sent from cross site domain

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am using laravel as backend and angujarjs as frontend to make an application. The frontend is sitting in another server, and therefore I have to deal with cross domain policy. I have enabled CORS, so I can "send" post request. 
The problem is that when I am trying to get Input::all() in laravel, the request gets cancelled. (status shown 'cancelled' in Chrome network). But when I dont use Input, everything is OK.

```
//laravel
    class SessionController extends BaseController {

    protected $entity;

    public function __construct(SessionEntity $entity)
    {
        $this->entity = $entity;
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return Response::json('hello')->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }

    public function postLogin()
    {
        //$data = Input::all();
        //return Response::json($data);
        // $user = $entity->login($data);
        // if($user)
        // {
        //  return Response::json($user);
        // } else {
        //  return Response::json($entity->errors(), 400);
        // }


//the code below is OK (able to send response back) , but the code above is not, because I am using Input::all()
        $data = array(
            "email" => "324234",
            "password"      => "654321"
        );
        return Response::json($data);
    }

}
```

//angularjs

```
.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.send = function(credential) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/session/login',
                data: credential,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(headers);
            });
        };
    }]);
```

Here's the headers to enable CORS

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{

    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1728000');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    return $response;

});
```

What did I miss??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I use namespace but didn't include 'use Input'.
silly me...

Also, I found that I have to explicitly set Content-Type to 'application/json' in order to receive data using Input::all() in laravel, otherwise I get no data.

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain requests you must use **[jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)** instead **json**